# Multiple color border around image

Tags: css, image, border

How can I create a 2 color border like this around an image?

Like this:

[image]

This is for an HTML website. What CSS should I use? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What technology are you talking about?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Is this for a website? If so are you familliar with css?

Comment: This is for HTML website. What CSS codes should I use? @simbabque

Comment: Yes i am little familiar with CSS @JacobGoulden

Comment: You easily could google this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Comment: @JacobGoulden [W3Fools.](http://www.w3fools.com/). Try not to use them as a reference

Comment: Yes, It's possible...What have you tried ?

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/U7XXN/)

**CSS**

```
 #mainDiv {
     height: 200px;
     width: 560px;
     position: relative;
     border-bottom: 8px solid #f51c40;
     background: #3beadc;
    border-top: 4px solid yellow;
  }

 #borderLeftbottom  {
   border-left: 8px solid #f51c40;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   bottom: 0;
 }
#borderRightbottom{
  border-right: 8px solid #f51c40;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   bottom: 0;
   right:0;
}
#borderLefttop  {
  border-left: 4px solid yellow;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 50%;
}
#borderRighttop{
   border-right: 4px solid yellow;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 50%;
   right:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainDiv"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="google" />
     <div id="borderLeftbottom"></div>
     <div id="borderRightbottom"></div>
     <div id="borderLefttop"></div>
     <div id="borderRighttop"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Fully reusable solution for any image - just need to wrap it with a div with class .multipleBorder**

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/tzfv2/7/)

1) Wrap the image in a div.

2) Give the div padding: say 12px - 10px for outer border and 2px for inner border

3) Create pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` the div - each with 50% height

4) Set a border and background for each pseudo element (background is used as inner border)

5) Remove the bottom border of the top element and the top border of the bottom element.

**Done!**

### Markup

```
<div class="multipleBorder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x150" alt="" width="600px" height="150px" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.multipleBorder
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px;
}
.multipleBorder:before, .multipleBorder:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 10px solid silver;
    border-bottom: none;
    background: maroon;
    z-index: -1;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}
.multipleBorder:after
{
    bottom:0;
    top: auto;
    border: 10px solid maroon;
    border-top: none;
    background: silver;
}
```

Comment: I like the use of :before and :after +1

Comment: Yes, and the beauty of this is that we only have 2 elements in the markup!